# order by next and previous

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have SQL table in MySQL with the following information:

```
id | prev | next
1  | 7    |  2
2  | 1    |  3
3  | 2    |  6
4  | 6    |  5
5  | 4    |  null
6  | 3    |  4
7  | null |  1
```

I want to use SQL query to order it ascending by next column or descending by prev column where next is a pointer to the next row and previous is a pointer to the previous row so if I want to order ascending for example I will get the result as the following:

```
id | prev | next
7  | null |  1
1  | 7    |  2
2  | 1    |  3
3  | 2    |  6
6  | 3    |  4
4  | 6    |  5
5  | 4    |  null
```

So how to do that?

Update: The first table is ordered by id but I want to order it in a way where I get the second table, the second table is resulted by go through next value, so the first row is 7 (id=7) because prev is null and the second is 1 because the next column of first row is 1 and then the third row is 2 because 2 is the value of next column of second row and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `ORDER BY next ASC` or `ORDER BY prev DESC`

Comment: why in `next` column 6 go before 4 and 5 ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The first table is ordered by id but I want to order it in a way where I get the second table, the second table is resulted by go through next value, so the first row is 7 (id=7) because prev is null and the second is 1 because the next column of first row is 1 and then the third row is 2 because 2 is the value of next column of second row and so on.

Comment: @Strawberry MySQL 5.5

Comment: Ah, bad luck. This kind of thing is quite tedious prior to 8.0+

Comment: Options pre-MySQL 8.0 include joining the table to itself as often as could be required, writing a sproc, handling the recursion logic in application code, or switching to an alternative model, e.g. nested sets. All of these options have been widely discussed. Alternatively, upgrade!

Comment: @RiggsFolly no it is not normal sorting I think it is something like sorting by pointer but I can't find a native SQL solution for it in MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i found a solution with procedure.
when i have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE `zz_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prev` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

and the records:

```
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('1', '7', '2');
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('2', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('3', '2', '6');
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('4', '6', '5');
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('5', '4', null);
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('6', '3', '4');
INSERT INTO `zz_test` VALUES ('7', null, '1');
```

it can be sorted by this procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS zz_sort_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE zz_sort_test()
BEGIN

    DECLARE next_value INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE rows_count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE iterations INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cid, cnext, cprev INT DEFAULT NULL;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS sorted;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sorted (iter INT, id INT, prev INT, next INT);

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO rows_count FROM zz_test;

    #first row
    SELECT next INTO next_value FROM zz_test WHERE prev IS NULL LIMIT 1;
    SELECT id, prev, next INTO cid, cprev, cnext FROM zz_test WHERE next_value = next;
    INSERT INTO sorted (iter, id, prev, next) VALUES (-1, cid, cprev, cnext);

    loopy: LOOP
        SET iterations = iterations + 1;
        IF rows_count = iterations THEN
            LEAVE loopy;
        END IF;

        SELECT id, prev, next INTO cid, cprev, cnext FROM zz_test WHERE next_value = id;
        SET next_value := cnext;

        INSERT INTO sorted (iter, id, prev, next) VALUES (iterations, cid, cprev, cnext);
    END LOOP loopy;

    SELECT id, prev, next FROM sorted ORDER BY iter;

END
```

to explain what is happening in there:

- it creates temporary table for storing the selected data (*sorted*)
- selects count of rows from zz_test table (*rows_count*)
- selects minimal (without null) next value (*next_value*) and inserts row with it into temp table
- in the loop is saving next_value for next iteration to search by
- and number of iterations to know when to stop (*iterations*)
- rows into temporary table are inserted with iteration counter because at the end it will help with the sort
- at the end, simple return all sorted from temp table

you can call it by:

```
call zz_sort_test;
```

i tested it with mysql **5.7.18**

**EDIT:**
i edited the answer, so first selected row will be one with *prev* value = NULL
i added LIMIT 1 for situations where there will be more than one row with prev = NULL

Comment: I tried your solution on your data and I get correct results but there is a small problem which is the first row usually not necessary to have 1 value in next column for this reason if you changed this line: **SELECT MIN(next) INTO next_value FROM zz_test WHERE next IS NOT NULL;** to become **SELECT next INTO next_value FROM zz_test WHERE prev IS NULL;** so the solution will become generic because usually first row must have null in prev column because there is no record precede it, any way thank you for your solution and I will vote for it

Comment: hia, i edited the answer according to your request (start with row where prev is null)